# Analyzer marks a potential leak for this construct

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, analyzer

With the following code the analyzer marks the setMyDict selector call as a potential leak and in dealloc it states "Incorrect decrement of the reference count is not owned at this point by the caller"

```
- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
      [self setMyDict:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [[self myDict] release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@synthesize myDict = _myDict;
```

I do not understand this. I thought, that with the alloc init the object increases the retain count by one and the pointer is stored in _myDict through the synthesized property. If I use this code instead

```
- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    _myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [_myDict release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Analyzer does not complain. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The @synthesize provides you with a setter and getter for the object you're synthesizing.

A setter method looks something like this (taken from the Apple docs)

```
-(void)setMyDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)newDict {
    if (myDict != newDict) {
       [myDict release];
       myDict = [newDict retain];
    }
}
```

You're creating a leak when you do:

```
[self setMyDict:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]];
```

Because you never release the newly alloc'd dictionary.

A way to work around this is:

```
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[self setMyDict:dict];
[dict release];
```

This takes care of the leak.

In the dealloc method, you should use:

```
[myDict release]; // Or whatever your property is called.
```

Comment: I would add that you should never use the method form of reference in dealloc.So, never use self.propertyName of [self getPropertyName] to release. Doing so calls the methods which can have unpredictable results if your accessors are more complicated.

Comment: Or just use `[self setMyDict: [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]]`

Comment: Inspired by your real good comments, I read a lot more on property declarations and found the dynamic declaration of ivars by the 64-Bit Runtime. Unfortunately they are not usable with iPhone-Simulator. But if one want to reduce later re-work, when the feature is available for Simulator one should use the following:
in init: [self setMyDict: [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]]
in dealloc: [self setMyDict:nil]